# I want to join two tables in R which an exact match on one variable and a partial match on another variable

Tags: r

![enter image description here][1]

[image]

The two tables are given, I want to perform an exact match on customer id and cegedim columns and a partial match on Names column

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide your data as text rather than images, and let us know what you've tried so far and where you ran into issues. More focused and better researched questions usually attract better answers.

Comment: By partial match, do you mean you want the 2 first letters of name to match with each other?

Comment: As in from Names of table 1, it compares to Names from table 2 then compare the exact match on Customer ID and gives the result